# why more tag is not working in my wordpress site

Tags: read-more

As you can see in the below screenshot, I had insert the `<!--more-->` tag after 1st paragraph in this article https://igntimes.com/20-amazing-youtube-tricks-and-tips/
[image]

But it is not working, any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

The `<!--more-->` tag is a replacement for an excerpt. You want to use the excerpt or `<!--more-->` tag on you blog/archive page, NOT on single posts.

The `<!--more-->` tag will not work on a **single** post like this:

```
https://igntimes.com/20-amazing-youtube-tricks-and-tips/
```

However, it should work on the **blog** (in your case your homepage, `https://igntimes.com/`. *But you only show post-title and image here for every post in the grid, so it will not be visible*)

**or**

in your **category archive pages** (in your case, for example `https://igntimes.com/category/social/`. *But here the Youtube-Tricks post is only displayed at the top in your special grid, and you also only show title and image in the tiles, so it will also be not visible.*)

So please move the Youtube Post in the normal post list under your grid/tiles: (maybe just quickly change the date on that post)
[image]

Than you need to make sure that your archive templates are using `the_content()` and not `the_excerpt()`.

Than you should only see the content above the `<!--more-->` tag on the youtube post.